# link with ruby code and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm building an application using ruby on rails for the backend and js, ajax for the front end. In a html.erb file that I created, to listed all the elements of a certain "event", I implemented some ruby code into the html which it was fine... but I came up with this page that it has been created for someone else in ajax... All I want to do is to put a link that redirects me on anoter page... 
For my file I used this line of code to redirect me on the page I want

```
 <a href='/events/<%= event.id %>'>Click for details...</a>
```

How can I do the same in the ajax script?

```
 var $newDiv = $(html);
```

I would like to append to this $newDiv the link I showed before or something equivalent... How can I do it?

I hope my question is clear

Comment: Your question is unclear, please provide more informations about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - here is how I would do this with jQuery.

Step 1:

Create a route on your server that has the data you would like to include on the page. That might be the id of the event, for example.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Step 2:

Write some javascript that makes a GET request to the route you just created. e.g:

```
$.get( "some/rails/route", function( data ) {
  // do stuff with the data you got back here
  console.log(data);
});
```

Step 3:

With the id you got from the server, create an `<a>` tag whose href goes something like:

```
<a href="/events/3"></a>
```

(if the id was 3)

e.g:

```
var newLink = $("<a />", {
  href : "/events/" + data.id,
  text : "Click for details..."
}).append($("some_dom_element"));
```